# Powershell: Write-Output -NoEnumerate not suppressing output to console

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm writing a function in PowerShell that I want to be called via other PowerShell functions as well as be used as a standalone function. 
With that objective in mind, I want to send a message down the pipeline using `Write-Output` to these other functions. 
However, I don't want `Write-Output` to write to the PowerShell console. The [TechNet page for Write-Output](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) states:

> Write-Output:
>
> > Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console.
> >
> > > -NoEnumerate:
> > >
> > > > By default, the Write-Output cmdlet always enumerates its output. The NoEnumerate parameter suppresses the default behavior, and prevents Write-Output from enumerating output. The NoEnumerate parameter has no effect on collections that were created by wrapping commands in parentheses, because the parentheses force enumeration.

For some reason, this -NoEnumerate switch will not work for me in either the PowerShell ISE or the PowerShell CLI. I always get output to my screen.

```
$data = "Text to suppress"
Write-Output -InputObject $data -NoEnumerate
```

This will always return 'Text to suppress' (no quotes).

I've seen people suggest to pipe to `Out-Null` like this:

```
$data = "Text to suppress"
Write-Output -InputObject $data -NoEnumerate | Out-Null
$_
```

This suppresses screen output, but when I use `$_` I have nothing in my pipeline afterwards which defeats the purpose of me using Write-Output in the first place.

System is Windows 2012 with PowerShell 4.0

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've never had to use it myself, but -NoEnumerate sounds more like a switch that causes array output to actually output an array rather than enumerating the values inside the array upon output. As far as avoiding objects going to the console, redirect any output to a variable or pass it directly to the next function. You could go as far as including instructions for when the cmdlet is called alone, or if it is called from within the pipeline if it is absolutely critical that no output make it to the console. ($MyInvocation.PipelinePosition will help with this)

Comment: I am not  sure, what you are trying to do. Actually if you use `Write-Output` and pipe the content of `$data` to another function, the host won't write the content of your output stream to the console, so there is nothing to suppress. If you want to suppress the console output when you are not piping the output stream to another function, then clearing your output stream by piping it to `Out-Null` will have exactly this effect. That the automatic variable `$_` is empty is normal, if you are not using it as a placeholder in a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Write-Output doesn't write to the console unless it's the last command in the pipeline. In your first example, Write-Output is the only command in the pipeline, so its output is being dumped to the console. To keep that from happening, you need to send the output somewhere. For example:

```
Write-Output 5
```

will send "5" to the console, because Write-Output is the last and only command in the pipeline. However:

```
Write-Output 5 | Start-Sleep
```

no longer does that because Start-Sleep is now the next command in the pipeline, and has therefore become the recipient of Write-Output's data.

Comment: This doesn't work because Start-Sleep doesn't take string values. Tried other things, but I couldn't find anything that doesn't print to the screen (`Format-Table`) or edit the string in some fashion.

Comment: The Start-Sleep example was to show that Write-Output does not always write to the console; only when it is the last command in the pipeline. Write-Output doesn't write string values, it writes PSObjects to the pipeline, which the Start-Sleep then interprets as an integer value. if Write-Output is the last command on the pipeline, the PSObject is passed to the console, which displays a text representation of the PSObject that was passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Write your function as you have written it with Write-Output as the last command in the pipeline.  This should send the output up the line to the invoker of the function.  It's here that the invoker can use the output, and at the same time suppress writing to the console.

```
  MyFunction blah, blah, blah | % {do something with each object in the output}
```

I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it works.  But it seems plausible.

Answer (score 0):

My question is not the greatest.

First of all `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` doesn't suppress output on `Write-Output`.

Secondly, `Write-Output` is supposed to write its output. Trying to make it stop is a silly goal.

Thirdly, piping `Write-Output` to `Out-Null` or `Out-File` means that the value you gave `Write-Output` will not continue down the pipeline which was the only reason I was using it.

Fourth, `$suppress = Write-Output "String to Suppress"` also doesn't pass the value down the pipeline.

So I'm answering my question by realizing if it prints out to the screen that's really not a terrible thing and moving on. Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly storing the output in a variable would be more prudent than trying to use an implicit automatic variable. As soon as another command is run, that implicit variable will lose the prior output stored in it. No automatic variable exists to do what you're asking.

If you want to type out a set of commands without storing everything in temporary variables along the way, you can write a scriptblock at the command line as well, and make use of the $_ automatic variable you've indicated you're trying to use.

You just need to start a new line using `shift + enter` and write the code block as you would in a normal scriptblock - in which you could use the $_ automatic variable as part of a pipeline.